# Do I need to setup OAuth in my application if I want to setup in-app purchases?

Tags: android, oauth, google-play

My application is very simple and doesn't require any personal data from user for the moment. It's just a simple game, and the data is stored on user's device. But I decided to move further, and to add possibility to buy additional features, using in-app purchases. The app is for Android, and published on Google Play. So, right now I am wondering if I need to connect OAuth (that Google suggests), if I actually don't need any personal data from the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a server-side for your app the possibility of your App being cracked will increase and users can simulate payment without actually paying.
That's Why Google recommends verifying payments using the server to server APIs. You can use third-party solutions like RevenueCat.com or Adapty.io for that purpose if you don't want to develop a server for your app.

Comment: Thank you for a complete and clear answer

Answer (score 1):

No You do not need to, but it is preferable.
Google Play IAP is fairly secure and enough for you.
you can use Google firebase when you need to store some data for users, it is very secure if you use it will.
but for now do not worry.